# Can I make custom Easing fuction in React Native?

Tags: animation, react-native, easing

I'm trying to use react native Animated API for some header Animation like this:
https://yalantis.com/blog/toolbar-jelly-animation-kotlin-android/

I managed to transform the [SVG component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K3tx.gif) using [Animate.timing](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.51/animated.html#timing) and [some easing functions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.51/easing.html), but I wasn't satisfied at these basic easing functions and want to make **my own easing function** like [this](https://github.com/Yalantis/JellyToolbar/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/yalantis/jellytoolbar/interpolator/JellyInterpolator.kt).

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply your own easing function as the easing property of the Animated.timing() config object rather than the predefined ones.

The code might be like this:

```js
    const bezierQuad = (t: number) => {
      return Math.min(1.0, Math.sin(28 * t - 6.16) / (5 * t - 1.1))
    }

    Animated.timing(...., {
      toValue: ...,
      duration: ...,
      easing: bezierQuad,
    }).start(() => {
    });
```

Comment: Thanks!  Making my own easing function like 'customEasing(t) {return ...}' and supplyig it in easing property(easing : this.customEasing) work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since the type of [TimingAnimationConfig](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/37436752f5871625ca8fa4778ff165a151fbb691/Libraries/Animated/src/animations/TimingAnimation.js#L22) is like this:

```js
export type TimingAnimationConfig = {
  ...AnimationConfig,
  toValue:
    | number
    | AnimatedValue
    | {
        x: number,
        y: number,
        ...
      }
    | AnimatedValueXY
    | AnimatedInterpolation,
  easing?: (value: number) => number,
  duration?: number,
  delay?: number,
};
```

The type of the ease function is like this:

```js
(value: number) => number
```

The code might be like this

```js
    const bezierQuad = (t: number) => {
      return Math.min(1.0, Math.sin(28 * t - 6.16) / (5 * t - 1.1))
    }

    Animated.timing(...., {
      toValue: ...,
      duration: ...,
      easing: bezierQuad,
    }).start(() => {
    });
```